# clarification on the local parameterization trick

Tags: bayesian, variational-bayes

I was reading Gregory Gundersen's [blog](http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2018/04/29/reparameterization/) entry on the local reparameterization trick

and at a certain point he writes

$$\nabla_{\theta} \mathbb{E}_{p_{\theta}(\bf{z})} [f_{\theta}(\bf{z})]=\int_{\bf{z}} (\nabla_{\theta} p_{\theta}(\bf{z})) f_{\theta}(\bf{z})  \,d\bf{z} +   \mathbb{E}_{Q_{\theta}(\bf{z})} [p_{\theta}(\bf{z})\nabla_{\theta} f_{\theta}(\bf{z})] $$

and then he says that the first term at the r.h.s.is not guaranteed to be an expectation.

can someone explain me why? what are the mathematical requirements that an expected value has to satisfy ? thanks

Comment: AFAIU, he means that this is not an expectation because $\nabla_{\theta} p_{\theta}(z)$ is not a probability distribution (it is a derivative / gradient of a distribution). Specifically, it does not have to integrate to 1, hence the first term is not an expectation.

Comment: ah right, that's true. i was focused on the expected value and i didn't consider the properties of $\nabla_{\theta}p_{\theta}(z) $. i wonder if there are other reasons other than this one though

Comment: @YairDaon hi , sorry if i ask again, but can you tell me also  why the presence of that term is a problem from a computational point of view?

Comment: again, AFAIU (I don't know much about VAEs): how would you go about calculating this integral? Numerical methods (e.g. Simson's methods take too much time in high dimensions. So you'd have to resort to MC. But $\nabla_{\theta} p_{\theta}$ is not a distribution so you can't just sample IID from it. There reparameterization trick seems to bypass this problem.